# Is there anyway to snap to vertices while using Edge Slide with Clamp Off?

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

I am a precision modeler, which means I like to be exact instead of "eyeballing" things when I model. I am very happy to see the option to Edge Slide with Clamping Off in v2.75a, but I don't seem to be able to snap the edge slide destination to a vertex point elsewhere on the model. Is this possible and I am just missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I've been having the same issue and managed to figure it out:

1. In Edit Mode, select an edge or a face that you want to use as a custom transform, this works also in object mode for objects.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>, this will align the view to selected in orthographic view.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space bar</kbd>, in order to create a custom transform.
4. In the Tool Shelf, that you can toggle it using <kbd>T</kbd>, under Create Orientation, at the bottom of the Tool Shelf, make sure you check Use View, this will align the new custom orientation to the view.
5. You can also rename the custom orientation to something meaningful. You can delete it or change it's name in the Properties Panel <kbd>N</kbd>.
6. Now you can use the new custom orientation instead of the default orientation, such as Global or Normal..etc. Don't use slide because it will still not react to snap, instead use transforms to move <kbd>G</kbd>, rotate <kbd>R</kbd> or scale <kbd>S</kbd> using the new custom transform, you can still lock axis and toggle between Global and custom transform using shortcuts.
   Check Blender Documentation on Custom Orientations:
   https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#custom-orientations

   [image: custom orientation properties]
   [image: custom transform]

Comment: Thanks for the help Georges. I posted a tutorial on this here https://youtu.be/aaL05JYEP9o if it helps to see it in video form. I used a more simplified approach as sambler posted.

Comment: Very nice, helpful tutoria! What software are you using to record?

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I use:  http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm and I love it.

Comment: Transform is not the same as slide for faces. Transforms won't scale the face linearly like slide does.

Answer (score 4):

Edge slide has always had an issue with snapping. There is a slow workaround that suggests that this could be improved.

With the edge selected that you plan to slide along, create a [custom transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#custom-orientations) and enable it, then move the vertex <kbd>G</kbd> and lock to the local axis that follows the edge (should be Y) by double tapping the axis <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>. While transforming along this custom axis snapping can be utilised.