# Edge Sliding multiple verts/edges along a single edge axis?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am looking for a way of using the GG edge slide feature to move multiple verts/edges with different normals, all in the same direction.
Attached are some screenshots of the issue...
I would like to move all the edges/verts highlighted up the angle of the faces above them (see red arrow), but need them to retain their own angles.
If I select them all and GG to slide, they all slide off in their own different directions, if I choose to move them in the 'Normal' axis, the axis is not the desired one due to them having different normal directions.

The only way I can find to do it is to just move edges with the same normal direction, but this then involves multiple selections and edge slides, surely there is some way of doing them all at once?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works for me [as expected](http://imgur.com/S8AtUOd), however you can try another method which involves using *View* transform orientation. Select face, *along which* you'd like to move selection and align view to it (`Shift`+`Numpad1`). Choose *View* trnaform orientation. Select your faces and grab them along desired view axe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, mine does behave the same as in your video but only when the selected faces are all facing the same direction. In my situation, I have added edge loops around the corners, so there are faces that are facing at right angles to the main faces, having these selected as well results in my issue.
However, your 'View' orientation solution works perfectly, I created a vertex group with the verts I wanted to move and moved them along the view axis of the faces above, not as simple as selecting and sliding, but the end result is the same - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a custom transform.
Select an edge that represents the orientation of your desired transform, in your case, this will be where the red arrow is pointing, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Space bar</kbd>  this will create custom transform using the orientation of the selected edge, now you can use this new transform to move your mesh along.
 For example if you want to move the selected vertices/edges/faces on the new Y axis, select them, press <kbd>G</kbd> to move, then press <kbd>Y</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>, this will change the orientation from the default Global to the new custom transform. 
You can edit the parameters of your custom transform immediately after creating it in the tool's   shelf to the left of the 3D view, if you can't see it use <kbd>T</kbd> to show it. You can rename and delete the custom transform in the properties shelf to the right of your 3D view, use <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle it's visibility.

Comment: Also check this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaL05JYEP9o&feature=youtu.be
And a slightly related question here
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33810/is-there-anyway-to-snap-to-vertices-while-using-edge-slide-with-clamp-off/52249#52249

Comment: Great tip, I didn't know you create a custom transform, that's must easier than the other solution. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

As detailed by Mr Zak, the solution to this issue is -

- Select the verts you want to move
- Make a vertex group of out them
- Select the face along which you want to move your verts
- Use SHIFT+NUM1 to align the view to that angle
- Press 'A' to deselect the face and then select your vertex group
- Change the transform orientation to 'View'
  Now you can move the selected verts in the desired angle.