# Edge slide and snapping to vertex on a cilinder doesn't work with the custom transform orientation workaround

Tags: modeling, snapping

So I was trying to slide a vertex along an edge, as shown here

[Is there anyway to snap to vertices while using Edge Slide with Clamp Off?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33810/is-there-anyway-to-snap-to-vertices-while-using-edge-slide-with-clamp-off)

But my problem is that is not giving me the point of the intersection. Is there a virable I might be missing out like the edge I should constraint to, or what I want is something different?

[image]

Comment: This is a frustrating aspect of Blender's snap system. Even if you used snap to edge, rather than vertex, as shown, it would still only drop an arbitrary perpendicular.  (Snap has been modified somewhat in 2,8, but I haven't tried it?) I use the TinyCad  add-on to put a vertex at the intersection between 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that the direction it snaps to is the perpendicular of the custom transformation.
In this particular case I could get by using the knife tool without hassle, but there may be other cases where the workaraund would be too long and distracting