# Edge/Vertex Slide and snapping

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to snap to vertices oder edges while using edge/vertex slide?

I'm specifically using edge and vertex slide because I need to keep the UVs, so the already mentioned workaround using custom transforms doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. If this is the link that you are referencing as not helping I suggest including that in the question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33810/is-there-anyway-to-snap-to-vertices-while-using-edge-slide-with-clamp-off/52249