# Need to fill in a hole in a curved mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to fill this hole in a curved mesh and have tried using <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and *Bridge Edge Loops* to fill in loops, but neither has worked.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrZxN.jpg]

Comment: It is hard to get a picture what is going on ... share more screens or share blend file via https://blend-exchange.com (copy-paste given code into your Q by edit). Like now it seems you would have to start from scratch :)

Comment: What vklidu has suggested is probably the best way to get an answer. However, you might try selecting the edges around the area you want to fill, then Ctrl+F, from that menu that opens select Grid Fill. Here is a YouTube ~6 minute tutorial about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vApGpkd05x4

Answer (score 0):

That's a scary-looking mesh and it may be time-consuming to repair.
You didn't really specify how your 'bridge edge loops' failed, but typically it's because you've selected invalid loops or only one loop.

[image]

If you select only the "vertical" edges you can see that bridge edge loops should fire as long as there are the same amount of vertices in both loops.

[image]

you will of course have to repair the bridge by adding more loops and [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33810/is-there-anyway-to-snap-to-vertices-while-using-edge-slide-with-clamp-off).

@curious_1 also pointed out that the 'Grid fill' is an option. This maybe won't work as seamlessly for your monster mess as it did for this triangulated torus, but maybe it's the magic function you need.
(note that, unlike bridge edge loops, grid fill requires you to select the edges all the way around the offending hole.)

[image]